# Connecting to kinesis stream error. Is it role related?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am trying to connect to a kinesis stream to grab a record because I want to see how this record is processed by AWS Lambda. In order to view a record on Kinesis, I am trying to first run:

```
aws kinesis describe-stream --stream-name <stream_name>

An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the DescribeStream operation: Stream <stream_name> under account <some_number> not found.
```

So the stream exists. Is this possible that this is role/policy related?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your are doing this from an EC2 instance. The EC2 instance role or if user is configured using aws cli doesn't have appropriate permission. Do the below

1. Go to IAM
2. Locate role/user
3. Attach policy 'AmazonKinesisFullAccess'

This should work. Restrict your permissions as needed.

If this helps then upvote or mark this as an accepted answer so that it helps others